# Effects of currents on peak wave frequency

Tags: ocean, waves

I have been analyzing the surface wave measurements taken from the location where the waves interact with both opposing and following currents.

I don't understand why the peak frequency decreases when the waves interact with a strong opposing or following current. Can anyone help me understand that?

Comment: What types of waves are they? Rossby waves? Poincare waves? Gravity waves? Tide?

Comment: Are you saying the peak frequency always reduces when there is a background current, no matter if it is in the direction of wave propagation or against it?

Comment: Can you please provide more context to your question? What do you see from the measurments? What are the measured waves like, e.g. frequency, height etc.? How strong is the current? Is it spatially varying? Plots of your measurements would help a lot.

Comment: If a wave train encounters an opposing current, wouldn't there necessarily be an increase in frequency?

Comment: @42 In general, opposing current decreases frequency, following current increases it. I suspect there are more processes at play in this situation but it is impossible to tell without more information.